# Not valid value: <map>: [object Object] when trying to set map to drawing manager

Tags: google-maps

Have this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&sensor=true">
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
            #map-ubicacion {   width: 450px;
                        height: 400px;  }
 </style>

  <div class="map-ubicacion" id="map-ubicacion"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     var map;
     var elevator;
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 6,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(-32.73, -56.),
         mapTypeId: 'terrain',
         streetViewControl: false,
         navigationControl: true,
         navigationControlOptions:
     {
         style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ANDROID
     }
     };

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-ubicacion'), myOptions);


     var draw= new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
         drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
         drawingControl: true,
         polygonOptions: {
             clickable: true,
             draggable: true,
             editable: true,
             fillColor: '#ffff00',
             fillOpacity: 0.8,
             strokeWeight: 5
         }
     });
     draw.setMap(map);
   </script>
```

and when i load it:
Error: Valor no válido para la propiedad : [object Object]
...tf,a),this.b&&this.b(a))};va(gg[H],function(a){var b=this.ta,c=Tf(a);b[c]&&(dele...

I couldnt find any solution googling it, any idea?

Comment: I don't get that error with [the code you have posted](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_DrawingManager.html), although I can see how you might as you don't initialize the map in an onload function.

Comment: What? Should i initialize the map? You dont do it in that code, dont you?

Comment: please post a link to that page, we can't help you without it because the code as it is works fine, there must be another issue

Comment: If you post a complete page (or a link to a page that generates the error), we might be able to answer your question.  As Dr. Molle said, the code you posted works for me and it doesn't generate the error you reported, so there is something else wrong.  As I said, I could see how you might be getting the initialization wrong yielding  that error (a fix would be to put the javascript that initializes the map in a function that runs _after_ the page loads.